# Update Primary table with String match from another table

Tags: sql-server

This is my table structure

```
Temp_camp(id int identity,email varchar(100),shot_id bigint)
insert into Temp_camp values(email)('xyz@gmail.com'),('y2k@yahoo.com'),('maaki@quora.com')
```

and other table structure

```
tb_adhar(shot_id bigint,email varchar(100))
insert into tb_adhar values(100,'xyz@gmail.com'),(200'y2k@yahoo.com')
```

The `tb_adhar` get a bulk load after 6PM with `10^6 records` every day..

so  i need to update Temp_Camp(shot_id) with shot_id from `tb_adhar`

i wrote this query but it takes quite a long time to procees!

here is the query

```
update temp_camp
set shot_id=t.Shot_id from tb_adhar t join temp_camp c on t.email=c.email
```

`I only wanted to know if there are bugs in code?? i dont want to mess up with the client data!`

Comment: Put Primary Keys in both the tables

Comment: Thers no relation between 2 tables just email that uniquely identies records!

Answer (score 0):

What you could do to increase performance if you haven't done so already. Since you are joining tables on `email` you could add additional index on `email` column on both tables and then on `tb_adhar` table include `shot_id` column in the index.
I should note that adding these indexes will reduce the speed at witch inserts are being done.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX Temp_camp_index_email 
ON Temp_camp(email)

GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX tb_adhar_index_email 
ON tb_adhar (email)
INCLUDE (Shot_id);

GO
```

Comment: there are indexs defined on columns thanks to `DBA` !

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is OK but you're doing pretty big update and SQL Server doesn't like that much. I had similar issue and I resolved it by splitting the whole operation into smaller transactions. Try this out:

```
DECLARE 
@ChunkSize int = 100000,
@ChunkNumber int,
@ChunkID int = 0

SELECT @ChunkNumber = COUNT(*) / @ChunkSize + 1
FROM tb_adhar

WHILE @ChunkID < @ChunkNumber
BEGIN
    update temp_camp
    set shot_id=t.Shot_id 
    from (select * from (
            select tt.*, 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) rnum
            FROM tb_adhar tt) 
           WHERE rnum BETWEEN @ChunkID * @ChunkSize AND (@ChunkID + 1) * @ChunkSize) t  
        join temp_camp c on t.email=c.email

    SET @ChunkID += 1
END
```

One more thing: you're saying that tb_adhar table gets 10^6 new records every day. Try to find a way to identify only new records. Otherwise your query does the same thing every time - let's say it updates 20mil old rows to the same values and 1mil new rows - the actual useful work.